# IDE can't find declaration of element in xsl file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-neon, java-5

I work on an old java 5 project but I can't run it.
Before I try to run it, Eclipse (Neon.2 Release 4.6.2) indicate to me this error:

```
cvc-elt.1 cannot find the declaration of element xsl:stylesheet
```

Here, the xml code which is in error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />
    ....
    ....
```

Eclipse indicate the error on this line (line 3):

```
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
```

I understand the error but I don't know how to resolve it.
What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: eclipse neon requires java version 8 minimum

Comment: I don't know eclipse in any detail, but somehow you have things configured so that it is looking for a schema for the XSLT vocabulary, and failing to find one. You shouldn't normally be applying schema validation to a stylesheet, and you need to find the configuration settings that caused this to happen.

Comment: Exactly, I have java 8. I thought the project could work with java 8 ... Maybe not so. Thanks Michael Kay, I'm going to look in this direction.

Comment: @harshakumarReddy While it's true that Eclipse Neon requires Java 8 to run, you can still use lower versions of Java for your projects within Neon.

Comment: It seems to be a false error because its works correctly when I run my server. Eclipse pushed me in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when there are spaces in the filename.  Once removed, the error no longer appears.  I am not using the same version of Eclipse though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).